# Split observations in half

Tags: r

In a plot(x,y) is there any way to plot a line/curve/function that would split **at every x (see DWins [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867160/split-observations-in-half/8867445#comment11085049_8867445)) ** the observations in 2 halfs? So that **at arround every x (see DWins [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867160/split-observations-in-half/8867445#comment11085049_8867445)) ** the same number of observations are above and below this line/curve/function? Is there any way to get the (x,y) coordinates or the function of this line/curve/function?

As regressing the data is problematic due to outliers/non-normality etc etc, i though a programming method might provide a viable solution without resorting to complicated regression methods.

Thanks a lot

Comment: quantile regression might be a good idea (see the `quantreg` package), for fitting a model to the median of `y` as a function of `x` ...

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could provide me an example or a function of the quantreg package to start with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First generate some test data:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
y <- seq_along(x)
```

Now assuming the data is sorted by `x` calculate the median at each `x` and plot:

```
plot(y ~ x)

m <- tapply(y, x, median)
lines(m ~ unique(x))
```

Comment: DWins solution seems to work better with my data, but your answer is simpler and does what the question asks and thus I give the answer to you. My problem is that the unique() trims a lot of my data away. A local regression for the data I have seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing Bolker's idea is really quite simple. This is just plotting the results of the first example in package quantreg's `rq` function

```
require(quantreg)
 data(stackloss); fit <- rq(stack.loss ~ Air.Flow, .5, data=stackloss)
 with(stackloss,   plot(Air.Flow, stack.loss))
 abline(a=coef(fit)[1], b=coef(fit)[2])
```

However that is not an "at every point" solution, so consider this `loess` approach:

```
fit <-loess(stack.loss ~ Air.Flow, data=stackloss, family="symmetric")
plot(stack.loss ~ Air.Flow, data=stackloss)
with(stackloss, lines(sort(unique(Air.Flow)),  
                      predict(fit, data.frame(Air.Flow=sort(unique(Air.Flow))))))
```

It doesn't do well at the x vlaues where there is only one value but it seems to hit pretty close to the median when using the family="symmetric" option.

Comment: Fantastic!!! Why is the 'family="symmetric"' option so critical? Where can I find more information on this (the help is not very helpful either)

Comment: As I read the documentation, if you accept the default you would be getting estimates of the local mean rather than the median. I did think that @G.Grothendieck's approach was at once simpler and more accurate an implementation of what you asked for than mine.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck's solution even as simple as ti may look somehow malfunctions with my data.

Comment: He also wrote `rollapply` and that would seem to offer opportunities if the you are not meaning to say "at each point" but really meant to say "near each point". My function is giving you the "around each point" sort of answers.

Comment: Edit: I found whats wrong. The unique() in G.Grothendieck's solution trims a lot of my data away. A locally weighted regression for the data I have seems to be a better solution

Comment: Thanks DWin. I edited my question to include your clarifications.